# How do I create a new table every day using CREATE EVENT?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, snapshot, dbeaver

I am trying to take daily snapshots for my view I have in my MariaDB database that I am accessing through DBeaver. Here is my code:

```
CREATE EVENT view_snapshot
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2022-11-12 00:00:00'
    DO
        CREATE TABLE snapshot AS
        select * from view1
```

I want to create a new table every day at midnight, so snapshot_11_12_2022, snapshot_11_13_2022, snapshot_11_14_2022, snapshot_11_15_2022, etc. are created as new tables that are stored in a separate database. The snapshots consist of the SQL query under "DO" that selects all the data in the table "view1" at midnight and creates a new table with all the data selected. My questions are:

1.) Is this a good way to take daily snapshots in MariaDB? I'm afraid it might take a while to select and copy over all the data at midnight if there are a lot of new records. I'm not sure how else to do this.

2.) I saw there is a "mysqldump" feature, but I'm not really sure how to use it to do what I am doing above.

3.) How do I insert the current date the query is run as the table name, so snapshot_{current_date}?

Comment: What is your snaphot for - is it in addition to a full db backup, is the view a subset of 1 or a few tables, is it necessary at all if you timestamp data...

Comment: [System Versioned Tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/) is one way of making a view `AS OF` a date always available. As above, purpose here comes into play as to what's the ideal solution. On 3), [execute immediate](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/) is probably the easy way, but assuming this snapshot is for selecting, having indexes on the created table is a good idea.